# Cannot get inner content of '' because the contents are not literal

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to iterate over the contents of a Repeater containing an html table, and use the contents of each cell. This works fine for standard HTML components, but blows up when I try to use a control. The code below will print the value of the first cell, "Item #1", but will throw an HttpException when trying to access .InnerText of the second cell. The error is as follows:

```
Cannot get inner content of  because the contents are not literal.
```

I have tried to use RenderControl via this solution found elsewhere, which failed for two reasons; 1) it rendered the entire HTML of the first cell and 2) it still blew up when trying to access the second cell with the following message:

```
'LinkButton1' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside 
 a form tag with runat=server
```

Is there an easy way to get the LinkButton text I'm after? Repeater code and C# can be found below.

The repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="Table1" class="data">
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="Row" runat="server">
        <td>Item #1</td>
        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="DoSomething" 
             Text="Item #2" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

The C#:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Rep1.Items)
{
    HtmlTableRow row = item.Controls[0].FindControl("Row") as HtmlTableRow;

    foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.InnerText != string.Empty) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this please? I am in desperate need of an answer, as I get the same errors as you. I've even tried using System.Windows.Forms controls to get around this, but no joy.

Answer (score 30):

For anyone else who arrives here:

You cannot get `InnerHtml` or `InnerText` on a `Control` unless its contents are literal, i.e. there are not any server controls or controls with `runat="server"` inside it that required rendering

Comment: Could you please give a more specific example to fix the above problem? I am having the exact same issue. Thank you

Comment: You cannot fix it without redesigning the control so its contents are literal, remove any sub controls with runat="server"

Comment: Also, apparently an HTML comment gets parsed as "not a literal control", even if it's like `<!-- Comment -->` instead of `<%-- Comment --%>`.  That was what got me here.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate/recurse through any child controls in the Controls collection. When you get to a leaf node (no children), then access that control's `InnerText` property.

Answer (score 3):

RenderControl C#

```
StringWriter iSW = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter iHTW = new HtmlTextWriter(iSW);
iDiv.RenderControl(iHTW);
string iS = iSW.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Include

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    return;
}
```

RenderControl VB

```
Dim iSW As New StringWriter 
Dim iHTW As New HtmlTextWriter(iSW) 
iDiv.RenderControl(iHTW) 
Dim iS As String = iSW.GetStringBuilder().ToString()
```

Include

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
    Return
End Sub
```

Comment: This works!  Glad I read this before the below answer from 2013.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Also, make sure that you do not have anything such trying to access another view control while another view control is activated in a multi view control.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! This does not provide an answer to the question. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Answer (score -2):

string value = ((Literal)(cell.Controls[0])).Text

Comment: No that causes a cast error trying to cast a HTML control to a Literal. Does not work. Sorry