# How to access the html generated for a table in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am populating a GridView from a dataset. In the RowDataBound event I check various variables and, for example, set the rowspan and colspan of various cells - add borders - make some cells bold etc.

I need to get the html generated for the gridview (table) into a stringbuilder expression. Any ideas how to do this. I have a div surrounding the table - but if I write:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(dv.InnerHtml);
```

I am told 'Cannot get inner content of dvScroll because the contents are not literal'.

I just need to get the html for the table - as the form it is in when sent to the browser - into a string.

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610249/cannot-get-inner-content-of-because-the-contents-are-not-literal

Comment: Yes, I did look at that ... but it doesn't really do what I'm after. I want the whole of the html for a table.

Comment: _Why_ to you need the raw HTML?  There may be another way of getting what you need without having to extract the rendered HTML.